Cubic Character of 2
Proposition: If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then $x^3 \equiv 2 \pmod p$ is solvable if and only if there are integers $C$ and $D$ such that $p=C^2 + 27 D^2$.
Proof:

If $x^3 \equiv 2 \pmod p$ is solvable, so is $x^3 \equiv 2 \pmod \pi$ and thus $\pi \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. We have \begin{align*}
            4p=A^2+27B^2,
        \end{align*}where $A=2a-b$, $B=\frac{b}{3}$. Since $b$ is even, so are $B$ and $A$. Let $D=\frac{B}{2}$ and $C=\frac{A}{2}$. Then $p=C^2 + 27 D^2$.
Suppose, conversely, that $p=C^2 + 27D^2$. Then $4p=(2C)^2 + 27(2D)^2$. By uniqueness $B= \pm 2D$; i.e., $B$ is even, and thus so is $b$. It follows that $\pi=a+b \omega \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, and $x^3 \equiv 2 \pmod \pi$ is solvable. Since $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\omega]}{\pi \mathbb{Z}[\omega]}$ has $p=N(\pi)$ elements there is an integer $h$ such that $h^3 \equiv 2 \pmod \pi$. It is now easy to show that $h^3 \equiv 2 \pmod p$. If $\pi\mid h^3 -2$, then $\overline\pi\mid h^3 -2$ and $ \pi \overline\pi= p\mid (h^3-2)^2$. Consequently, $p\mid h^3-2$, and we are done with the proof.

I did not understand the converse proof. Can someone please help? I do not understand where the integer "h" is coming from!! This proposition is from Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen's A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory (Proposition 9.6.2).

What is $\pi$ here?  an Eisenstein integer?

@Disha See the first sentences of §4 of the same chapter.
